# error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, casting, malloc

I am trying to import a C library into my C++ project but I'm stuck with this error

> invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
>     uint8_t const* raw = static_cast(getPointerToData(id, message->data, message->length));
>                                                                                                   ^
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

This code compile well using C compiler but get this error using C++ one

```
bool XbusMessage_getDataItem(void* item, enum XsDataIdentifier id, struct XbusMessage const* message)
{
uint8_t const* raw = (getPointerToData(id, message->data, message->length));
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: you probably need `static_cast<const uint8_t*>(message->data)`. You didn't show a [mcve] with all the structures of your function.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the return value from getPointerToData to `const uint8_t*`. Implicit conversions between pointer types are not allowed in C++ but are in C.

Try:

```
uint8_t const* raw = static_cast<uint8_t const*>(getPointerToData(id, message->data, message->length));
```

Edit:
You can also use a C-style cast if you want to keep the C code C and not C++.

```
 uint8_t const* raw = (uint8_t const*)(getPointerToData(id, message->data, message->length));
```

Comment: That was quick! thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]
     uint8_t const* raw = static_cast<uint8_t const*>(getPointerToData(id, message->data, message->length));
                                                                                                         ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try using a C-style cast instead. Nevermind, it seems that one of the parameters to getPointerToData needed the cast as well. Static cast should work fine.

Comment: Dindn't work too. I solved with Jean-François Fabre answer, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This code posted by Jean-François Fabre works

```
uint8_t const* raw = (getPointerToData(id, static_cast<const uint8_t*>(message->data), message->length));
```

Thanks!